# How to obtain a reference to a Runnable instance passed to a Thread constructor using PowerMock(ito)?

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, mockito, powermock

There's a black box class which creates a `Thread` using its constructor accepting an instance of `Runnable` as the argument:

```
public class Service {

  public static Task implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

      doSomeHeavyProcessing();
    }
  }

  public void doAsynchronously() {

    new Thread(new Task()).start();
  }
}
```

I want to intercept the constructor call and get a reference to the passing `Task` implementing `Runnable`. This is the code so far:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Service.class)
public class ServiceTest {

  @Test
  public void testService() {

    ArgumentCaptor<Runnable> runnables = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Runnable.class);
    Thread thread = Mockito.mock(Trhead.class);
    whenNew(Thread.class.getContructor(Runnable.class)).
      withArguments(runnables.capture)).thenReturn(thread);

    new Service().doAsynchronously();

    System.out.println("all runnables: " + runnables.getAllValues());

    for (Runnable r : runnables.getAllValues()) r.run();

    // perform some assertions after the code meant to be executed in a new
    // thread has been executed in the current (main) thread
  }
}
```

Test execution will print out:

```
all runnables: []
```

Is there a way of grabbing a reference to all `Runnable` objects or `Thread` objects returned by the constructor? I want to execute the asynchronous code either in the current (main) thread or join created threads and perform assertions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your code had some typo errors, and once corrected it didn't work when tried in the IDE. The code throws a `VerifyError` about the `Task` initialization. Making `Task` `public` helped.

Once every was alright, your code worked as expected, meaning your runnables were captured.

Although I would go for this stubbing syntax instead :

```
whenNew(Thread.class).withParameterTypes(Runnable.class)
    .withArguments(runnables.capture()).thenReturn(mock);
```

You should investigate your real code to see if it got correctly stubbed.